# Coffeescript: Long polling or Continuous server checks if logged in

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, coffeescript

I wanted to change the ui if the user is currently logged in or no, I want to check if there are sessions set using javascript/coffeescript and ajax.

So I set up a code like this:

```
class Rcrtmnt
  constructor: () -> 
  variables:
    status: 0
  init: ->
    @checkStatus();
    @refresh();
    loginObj = new Login;
    loginObj.checkLogin();
  checkStatus: ->
    ui = new Ui;
    if @variables.status == 1
      ui.loggedIn();
    else 
      ui.loggedOut();
  refresh: ->
    #loop here
    setTimeout ( =>
      #do something $.post probably.
    ), 1000
```

How do I constantly check the server if there are sessions set, or if the user is ucrrently logged in.?